# MySQL in Docker init process very slow

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to create test env for my tomcat app with mysql8.

I use jenkins to upload databse init sql to server.

But mysql container get stuck at init step, docker logs show this:
`[Entrypoint]: /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: running /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/db.sql`, db.sql is about 400MB size.

Actually, init process, it took about 1 hour to complete. it is very very slow.

When container ready, i use navicat to restore the same data to the same mysql container, this time restore process only take 4 minutes to complete.

I think it is not problem of docker or centos.

How can i speed up the init process?

Here is my env:

```
System: CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908
Virtual machine: NO
Docker-CE Version: Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d
Docker-compose Version: docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
```

Here is docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    mysql:
        # container_name: "mysql8"
        command: [
            "--character-set-server=utf8mb4",
            "--collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci",
            "--lower_case_table_names=1",
        ]
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "123456"
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: "db_name"
        image: "mysql:8.0"
        restart: "no"
        ports:
            - "3306"
        volumes: 
            - "./initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:delegated"
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", 'mysqladmin', 'ping', '-h', '127.0.0.1', '-u', 'root', '-p$$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD' ]
            timeout: 10s
            retries: 180
```

Comment: Sounds like you are loading (or REloading?) a large dataset??

Comment: yes. about 650000+records. The weird thing is restore data very low speed during container starting, but become normal speed when container ready

Comment: If you store the loaded data in a "volume" outside docker, you won't need to reload when you start up the container.